# How to limit number of choices of a ManyToManyField to a specific number of choices

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I am trying to build a multiple choice quizzes Django app. I have a model named `Answer`, and another model named `Question`.

Here are the contents of `Answer`:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and this is `Question`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    correct_answer = models.ForeignKey('Answer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='correct_answers')
    other_answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')
```

I want to limit the number of choices of `other_answers` in `django-admin` to 3 answers only. How to do that?

Notes:

1. I am ok with re-modeling my models.
2. I will not use `django-forms`, I am only building an API for a mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for [Geoff Walmsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11699729/geoff-walmsley)'s answer which inspired me for the correct answer.

This is the solution:

**admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import Question
from django import forms


class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Question

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('other_answers').count() != 3:
            raise ValidationError('You have to choose exactly 3 answers for the field Other Answers!')


@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = QuestionForm
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit it to 3 specific answers I think you can use [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

If you want to just limit it to a max of 3 then you should use [django model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I want `other_answers` to be exactly 3 answers. I tried your solution but it failed as `clean` function is called before saving the record, which means `self.other_answers.count()` is always zero. However, your answer inspired me to the correct answer. Please read my answer if you want to have an idea about how to do it.